# Can the council make you cut down trees on your property?

Tags: united-kingdom, real-estate, trees

There is an ongoing dispute between a property I own and the council, they claim that some 20ft conifer trees that are on my property is preventing light and causing dampness in their property, also they claim that the tenant has health issues and demand us to remove the trees. as far as trimming them to 12ft or so they will just become stumps so it’s either keep them or remove.

Within the past few weeks a family member has been taking control and organised them to be cut to prevent further dispute, the initial agreement with an agent is that is we remove them they will provide a fence, now they have been cut to stumps they say they will not unless the stumps are removed.

What rights do they have and I have?

This question is aimed at persons who know about UK Law.

Comment: What is the "council?"  Is it a municipal governing body?

Comment: Well yes, they are responsible for social housing.

Comment: Tricky one this, as the council may be acting in two roles. One, as the local governing body, and two as a property owner just like you. In their communication, they should indicate in which capacity they are acting, by reference to the legal basis for their demands. The care for the tenant suggests they're acting as landlords.